# Synchronize PHP between two servers

Tags: linux

what you think is the best way to synchronize PHP code between two servers. One server i production and second is testing server. They have linux and are separated (have another IP). How would you solve synchronize PHP code, when you want send a PHP code from testing server to production?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Use git, and then `git pull` from the production server

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I install git to production without wipe? Or i must reinstall server and then install git?

Comment: You can just install git. No need to wipe it